# How to group only subsequent items with the same property using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have input that could look like this:

```
A   1   2   C,D
A   2   3   C,E
B   4   5   F
A   6   7
A   7   8   D
A   9   10  E
```

I store this in my model class:

```
public class Item {

public String Name {get;set;}
public int Start {get;set;}
public int End {get;set;}
public List<string> Orders {get;set;}

}
```

I tried to use Linq to merge all subsequent items if the items have the same name and generate a new item that has the start value of the first item in the group, the end value of the last item in the group and a union of all order lists. It should then look like this:

```
A   1   3   C,D,E
B   4   5   F
A   6   10  D, E
```

I tried the following Linq statement, however, it groups all As and Bs together, independent of whether there are any other items in between. What do I need to change? The union of the order list is also missing.

```
var groups = items.GroupBy(i => i.Name).ToList();

foreach (var group in groups)
{
   result.Add(new Item {
     Start = group.First().Start, 
     End = group.Last().End, 
     Name = group.First().Name });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a classic loop for this:

```
var List<List<Item>> groups = new List<List<Item>>()
var currentGroup = new List<Item> { items.First() };
int i = 0;
foreach(var item in items.Skip(1))
{
    if(currentGroup.First().Name != item.Name)
    {
        groups.Add(currentGroup);
        currentGroup = new List<Item> { item };
    }
    else
    {
        currentGroup.Add(item);
        if(i == items.Count - 2) 
            groups.Add(currentGroup);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Now you can continue with your code by iterating the `groups`-list.

Comment: Your result variable would acutally be his groups variable right?

Comment: Shouldn't it be i == items.Count - 1?

Comment: @RoflcoptrException No, the `-2`-part is due to the fact that I skipped the very first item in the `items`-list. Furthermore at the point I make that comparison `i` has the value of the previos iteration, so on the very first iteration `i` is equal to zero, making `items.Count - 2` zero also for a collection of only two items.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not the best or fastest way but I got bored:

```
int groupID = -1;

var result = items.Select((item, index) =>
{
    if (index == 0 || items[index - 1].Name != item.Name)
        ++groupID;

    return new { group = groupID, item = item };
}).GroupBy(item => item.group).Select(group =>
{
    Item item = new Item();

    var first = group.First().item;
    var last = group.Last().item;

    item.Name = first.Name;
    item.Start = first.Start;
    item.End = last.End;
    item.Orders = group.SelectMany(g => g.item.Orders).Distinct().ToList();

    return item;
});
```

The variable `items` should be your input collection like a `List<Item>`. The result will be stored in `result`. This is an `IEnumerable<Item>` but you may add `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` as you like to convert it to `List<Item>` or `Item[]`.

The result will contain new created items. I did this on purpose to not mess up the input data.

The trick here is to use a local variable as a group id. It is increased if it is the first item or the last item had a different name. Then we group by the group id and the rest of the code will just create the item. The `SelectMany` method will join all `Orders`-values from the entire group and `Distinct` will then remove all duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This is not done by Linq. I just played a bit using simpler methods. But it gives same result which you wanted.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Item
{
    public static List<Item> Database;

    static Item()
    {
        Database = new List<Item>();
    }

    public Item(string name, int start, int end, params string[] orders)
    {
        Name = name;
        Start = start;
        End = end;
        Orders = new List<string>();
        foreach (string s in orders)
            Orders.Add(s);
        //putting newly created Item to database
        Database.Add(this);
    }

    //overload for creating tmp Items in GroupThem(), could be done using optinional parameter
    public Item(bool AddToDatabase, string name, int start, int end, params string[] orders)
    {
        Name = name;
        Start = start;
        End = end;
        Orders = new List<string>();
        foreach (string s in orders)
            Orders.Add(s);
        if (AddToDatabase) Database.Add(this);
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Start { get; set; }
    public int End { get; set; }
    public List<string> Orders { get; set; }

    public List<Item> GroupedItems()
    {
        List<Item> groupedItems = new List<Item>();
        Item previous = Database[0];
        Stack<Item> sameItems = new Stack<Item>();

        foreach (Item item in Database)
        {
            if (previous.Name == item.Name)
            {
                sameItems.Push(item);
            }
            else
            {
                groupedItems.Add(GroupThem(sameItems));
                previous = item;
                sameItems.Push(item);
            }
        }
        groupedItems.Add(GroupThem(sameItems));
        return groupedItems;
    }

    private Item GroupThem(Stack<Item> sameItems)
    {
        string newName = "";
        int newEnd = 0;
        int newStart = int.MaxValue;
        List<string> newOrders = new List<string>();
        Item tmp = null;
        while (sameItems.Count > 0)
        {
            tmp = sameItems.Pop();
            if (tmp.Start < newStart)
                newStart = tmp.Start;
            if (tmp.End > newEnd)
                newEnd = tmp.End;
            foreach (string s in tmp.Orders)
                if (!newOrders.Contains(s))
                    newOrders.Add(s);
            newName = tmp.Name;
        }
        return new Item(false, newName, newStart, newEnd, newOrders.ToArray());
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string tmp = "";
        foreach (string s in Orders)
            tmp += " " + s;
        return "Name = " + Name + ", Start = " + Start + ", End = " + End +", Orders  = "+ tmp;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Item item1 = new Item("A", 1, 2, "C", "D");
        Item item2 = new Item("A", 2, 3, "C", "E");
        Item item3 = new Item("B", 4, 5, "F");
        Item item4 = new Item("A", 6, 7);
        Item item5 = new Item("A", 7, 8, "D");
        Item item6 = new Item("A", 9, 10, "E");

        foreach (Item item in item1.GroupedItems())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, I know, but I think the following solution will still help someone.
It includes the original `Item` class, enhanced with:

- A `ToString` method to simplify inspection.
- A `CreateSamples` method to generate the sample items.
- A bonus nested class `ComparerByStartAndEnd` to sort items based on `Start` and `End` properties.

The solution resides in the `EXTENSIONS.GroupWhenChanging` method and the `Item.FromGroup` method.

The `TEST` class provides code to verify everything works as expected.

The actual grouping logic (`EXTENSIONS.GroupWhenChanging`) simply implements an enumerator that **does not invoke Linq** methods and allocates only a `List` object for each group, thus **saving both in performance and memory resources**.
The method is generic and accepts a comparison predicate, so it is not restricted to the sample Item class.

The creation of the result items, representing the groups with merged orders, is kept in the separate method `Item.FromGroup`. It uses some Linq to ease the task.

The `TEST.Test` method does the following:

- Creates the list of samples.
- Ensures the samples are ordered based on Start and End.
- Enumerates the groups (by means of `GroupWhenChanging`) and creates the corresponing items (through `Item.FromGroup`).

The Item class:

```
public static class MODEL
{
    public class Item
    {
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public int Start { get; set; }
        public int End { get; set; }
        public List<string> Orders { get; set; }

        /// <inheritdoc/>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1} .. {2} {3}", this.Name, this.Start, this.End, string.Join(",", this.Orders));
        }

        public static Item? FromGroup(IEnumerable<Item> group)
        {
            var array = group as Item[] ?? group.ToArray();
            if (array.Length > 0)
            {
                var newName = array[0].Name;
                var newStart = array.Min(item => item.Start);
                var newEnd = array.Max(item => item.End);
                var newOrders = array.SelectMany(item => item.Orders).Distinct().OrderBy(orderID => orderID).ToList();

                var newItem = new Item()
                {
                    Name = newName,
                    Start = newStart,
                    End = newEnd,
                    Orders = newOrders
                };

                return newItem;
            }

            return null;
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Item> CreateSamples()
        {
            yield return new Item() { Name = "A", Start = 1, End = 2, Orders = new List<string>() { "C", "D" } };
            yield return new Item() { Name = "A", Start = 2, End = 3, Orders = new List<string>() { "C", "E" } };
            yield return new Item() { Name = "B", Start = 4, End = 5, Orders = new List<string>() { "F" } };
            yield return new Item() { Name = "A", Start = 6, End = 7, Orders = new List<string>() };
            yield return new Item() { Name = "A", Start = 7, End = 8, Orders = new List<string>() { "D" } };
            yield return new Item() { Name = "A", Start = 9, End = 10, Orders = new List<string>() { "E" } };
        }

        public sealed class ComparerByStartAndEnd : Comparer<Item>
        {
            /// <inheritdoc/>
            public override int Compare(Item x, Item y)
            {
                if (x == y)
                    return 0;

                return x.End.CompareTo(y.Start);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The EXTENSIONS class:

```
public static class EXTENSIONS
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhenChanging<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
    {
        List<T> group = null;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (group is null)
                group = new List<T>() { item };
            else if (predicate(group[group.Count - 1], item))
                group.Add(item);
            else
            {
                yield return group;
                group = new List<T>() { item };
            }
        }
        if (group is not null)
            yield return group;
    }
}
```

The TEST class:

```
public static class TEST
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        var items = MODEL.Item.CreateSamples().ToList();

        items.Sort(new MODEL.Item.ComparerByStartAndEnd());

        var groups = items
            .GroupWhenChanging((prev, next) => prev.Name == next.Name)
            .Select(MODEL.Item.FromGroup)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```